# Angular 12+: Is there a Simple way to apply display mask/pipe for Reactive Form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Reactive form, if user-input from keyboard is `1000000` expects to see `10,000.00`. So a pipe is needed. Found a few SO posts,

- **not working**, use [.valueChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294168/5063031), `.valueChanges` is underlined with curly braces, implemented in code below, error.
- **not working**, use [.value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577416/5063031), `.value` is underlined with curly braces error too.
  `[value]="fg.get('fcTest').value | number: '9.2-2'"`
- complicated, [subscription to patch the value in this video](https://youtu.be/3fVRbGQyZjs).

Seems like have to add some code to `subscribe` for value change event, no simple way?

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg">
    <input
        type="number"
        class="fc"
        placeholder="integer"
        formControlName="fcTest"
        id="fcTest"
        [value]="fg.get('fcTest').valueChanges |async | number: '9.2.2'"
    />
</form>
```

```js
fg: FormGroup;
    
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
        fcTest: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
}
```

Comment: The video is probably the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: Can you explain or demo what is not working, e.g. with the solution 2?

Comment: @Vega `error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` with `value` underlined in red curly line.

Comment: On which line is the error? probably you need to insert ? before ., like object?.property

Comment: @Vega solution 2, `[value]="fg.get('fcTest').value | number: '9.2-2'">`, the `.value` is underlined.

Comment: Test plase [value]="fg.get('fcTest')?.value | number: '9.2-2'">

Comment: @Vega Works! Would you post an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three quoted solutions should work, however the error you invoke says that the control is undefined or comes null as of data, so `value` property cannot be applied to null.
It is accessing the property of null, which obviously a reason to throw an error.
You can either type define the control, either, going by shortcut way, use optional chaining operator (?.)

```
[value]="fg.get('fcTest')?.value | number: '9.2-2'"
```

One other solution could be:

```
@input #fcTest
    ...
    
    [value]="fcTest.value | number: '9.2.2'" >
```

Answer (score 1):

### In the Video

I think what is shown in the video is actually a rather clean and elegant solution:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.fg.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
    this.fg.patchValue({
      money: this.currencyPipe.transform(form.money.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), 'EUR', 'symbol', '1.0-0')
    }, {emitEvent: false})
  })
}
```

### Minor Simplification

You can avoid having to subscribe to `valueChanges` in the `OnInit` by binding an event in the template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="fg">
    <input
      (keyup)="onChange()"
      type="text"
      class="money"
      placeholder="€"
      formControlName="money"
      id="money"
    />
</form>
```

And what `onChange()` would look like:

```js
onChange() {
  this.fg.patchValue({
    money: this.currencyPipe.transform(this.fg.value.money.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, ''), 'EUR', 'symbol', '1.0-0')
  }, {emitEvent: false})
}
```

Here is the above example in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t1t8sf).

Answer (score 1):

If your attempt with `[value]="fg.get('fcTest').value | number: '9.2-2'"` is giving errors in the IDE, try moving part of it to a function and use typings e.g

```js
// template
[value]="fcTestValue | number: '9.2-2'"

// component
get fcTestValue(): string {
   return (this.fc.get('fcTest')?.value || '') as string;
}
```

Comment: HTML: `[value]="fcTest.value | number: '9.2-2'"` got _error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'._ with .value underlined. TS: `get fcTest(): string { return this.fg.get('fcTest').value as string;}` got _Error occurs in the template of comonent_